# SQLAlchemy Add A Table To An Already Existing Database

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm attempting to add a table to an already existing Database in SQLAlchemy. My app.db is already compiled and populated with data. I'm just trying to add a new table to the database titled song_points. (The Database tracks songs over time)

My Models:

```
from app import db

class songs (db.Model):
    SongID = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    Artist = db.Column(db.String(120), primary_key=True)
    Title = db.Column(db.String(120), primary_key = True)
    def __repr__(self):
            return "%s, %s, %d\n" %(self.Artist, self.Title, self.SongID)

class points(db.Model):
    SongID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("songs.SongID"), nullable= False, primary_key=True)
    Genre = db.Column(db.String(25), primary_key=True)
    Points = db.Column(db.Integer)
    Date = db.Column(db.Date, primary_key=True)
    Rank = db.Column(db.Integer)
    def __repr__self(self):
            return "%d, %s, %d\n" %(self.SongID, self.Genre, self.Points)
class artist_points(db.Model):
    Artist = db.Column(db.String(120), primary_key=True)
    Points = db.Column(db.Integer)
    def __repr__self(self):
        return "%s, %d\n" %(self.Artist, self.Points)

class graphs(db.Model): 
    SongID = db.Column(db.String(120), db.ForeignKey("songs.SongID"), nullable = False, primary_key = True)
    URL = db.Column(db.String(120), primary_key=True)
    def __repr__self(self):
        return "%s, %s\n" %(self.SongID, self.URL)
```

And here was my db creation script:

```
from migrate.versioning import api
from config import SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
from config import SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO
from app import db
import os.path
db.create_all()
if not os.path.exists(SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO):
    api.create(SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO, 'database repository')
    api.version_control(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
else:
    api.version_control(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO, api.version(SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO))
```

This is the table I'm attempting to add:

```
class song_points(db.Model):
    SongID = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey("songs.SongID"), nullable = False, primary_key = True)
    Genre = db.Column(db.String(25), db.ForeignKey("points.Genre"), nullable = False, primary_key = True)
    Points = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

Comment: Have you created and run a migration since adding the model?

Answer (score 4):

```
song_points.__table__.create(db.session.bind)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: The answer is so simple that it is not clear what explanations may be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the steps described in the [Flask-Mega](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database).

Firstly, add you new table definition in models.py

```
class song_points(db.Model):
    SongID = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey("songs.SongID"), nullable = False, primary_key = True)
    Genre = db.Column(db.String(25), db.ForeignKey("points.Genre"), nullable = False, primary_key = True)
    Points = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

Secondly, add new db_migrate.py file for db upgrade:

```
import imp
from migrate.versioning import api
from app import db
from config import SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
from config import SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO
v = api.db_version(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
migration = SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO + ('/versions/%03d_migration.py' % (v+1))
tmp_module = imp.new_module('old_model')
old_model = api.create_model(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
exec(old_model, tmp_module.__dict__)
script = api.make_update_script_for_model(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO, tmp_module.meta, db.metadata)
open(migration, "wt").write(script)
api.upgrade(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
v = api.db_version(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
print('New migration saved as ' + migration)
print('Current database version: ' + str(v))
```

After that, run `python db_migrate.py` to reflect all the changes in models.py. I made the code running locally. Let me know if you still cannot make it work.

BTW, there should be one correction in your code. SONGID should be integer type.

```
class graphs(db.Model): 
    SongID = db.Column(db.String(120), db.ForeignKey("songs.SongID"), nullable = False, primary_key = True)
```

To:

```
class graphs(db.Model): 
    SongID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("songs.SongID"), nullable = False, primary_key = True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just open terminal and type the following command:

```
from app import db
db.create_all()
exit()
```

Now open the database viewer and drop your database file. You must see the new table along with all old tables and their data.