# How to add new table in existing database of flask app using sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to add a new table in existing database without affecting existing tables and its datas. After adding new model class into models.py, what are steps needs to follow to add new table?

Comment: checkout this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030566/sqlalchemy-add-a-table-to-an-already-existing-database).
You may find it helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLAlchemy Add A Table To An Already Existing Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030566/sqlalchemy-add-a-table-to-an-already-existing-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've added the new model in your models.py, you just need to run `db.create_all()`. You can add this in your code somewhere (probably directly) after you initialize your app/database. Be sure to include `with app.app_context()` if you aren't calling `create_all` in a view. Hope this helps!

Comment: Will using ```db.create_all()``` reset the data in the existing tables?

Comment: I think create_all() first checks for the existence of the tables in the model and will only create tables that don't digging through the docs I found this example:  employees.create(engine, checkfirst=True) where checkfirst is True by default